# How to connect two real deviced with in Unity with Mirror?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, cross-platform, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

**I succesfully connected the editor and the PC build on the same device, but I can't connect the PC build or the editor to an Anrdoid mobile device.**

I enabled the multiplayer service, and the two device is connected to the same router.
I tried different tutorial projects and I always got the same results.
I tried both HOST and dedicated server methods, but nothing changed.
I using Unity 2019LTS, and android 6.
My PC is using wired connection, and my mobile device using wifi(they are both on the same router).
Any Ideas? I struggling with this problem since 2020 May.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNET is no longer supported, so use PHOTON instead.